# jQuery - Hiding only those that are visible

Tags: jquery

I have 5 buttons that either hide or show corresponding points on an SVG map. #icon1, #icon2, #icon3, #icon4, and #icon5 are the five buttons. .poi-hover is a class that is applied to all of the points on the map.

**jQuery Code for hide/show points**

```
var clickOne = true;
var clickTwo = true;
var clickThree = true;
var clickFour = true;
var clickFive = true;

$("#icon1").toggle(function () {
    clickOne = false;
    $(".outdoors").hide();
}, function () {
    clickOne = true;
    $(".outdoors").show();
});

$("#icon2").toggle(function () {
    clickTwo = false;
}, function () {
    clickTwo = true;
});

$("#icon3").toggle(function () {
    clickThree = false;
    $(".icons").hide();
}, function () {
    clickThree = true;
    $(".icons").show();
});

$("#icon4").toggle(function () {
    clickFour = false;
    $(".events").hide();
}, function () {
    clickFour = true;
    $(".events").show();
});

$("#icon5").toggle(function () {
    clickFive = false;
}, function () {
    clickFive = true;
});

$("#icon2, #icon3").click(function () {
    if (clickTwo == false && clickThree == false) {
        $(".groupsandicons").hide();
    } else {
        $(".groupsandicons").show();
    }
});

$("#icon1, #icon3").click(function () {
    if (clickOne == false && clickThree == false) {
        $(".agusta").hide();
    } else {
        $(".agusta").show();
    }
});

$("#icon1, #icon5").click(function () {
    if (clickOne == false && clickFive == false) {
        $(".lyons").hide();
    } else {
        $(".lyons").show();
    }
});

$("#icon4, #icon5").click(function () {
    if (clickFour == false && clickFive == false) {
        $(".ragbrai").hide();
    } else {
        $(".ragbrai").show();
    }
});
```

I am trying to make each point be able to hover and set all points that are visible to an opacity except for the one being hovered. I am doing this with the code below, but if I have any of the buttons turned off and hover on a visible point, it displays the points on the map that are supposed to be hidden. How do I fix this?

hover code:

```
$(".poi-hover").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(".poi-hover").not(this).css('opacity', 0.2);
        $(".button_pannel").css('opacity', 0.5);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(".poi-hover").css('opacity', 1);
        $(".button_pannel").css('opacity', 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: so you have 5 points, when you hover over one, the 4 others become less opaque?

Comment: remember that you can use `:visible` and `.not(':visible')` - http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use: `.is(':visible')` which will show visible ones

```
$(".poi-hover").on(
    {
        mouseenter: function()
        {
            //$(".poi-hover").css('opacity', 0.2);
            $('.poi-hover:visible').not(this).css('opacity', 0.2);
            $(".button_pannel").css('opacity',0.5);
        },
        mouseleave: function()
        {
            $(".poi-hover").css('opacity',1);
            $(".button_pannel").css('opacity',1);
        }
     });
```

Comment: I got it to work in a test on Fiddle, but not in my own code so its probably a problem I have somewhere. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting your code exactly right (it could probably be refactored to eliminate all those toggle functions), but one of these should work:

```
$('.poi-hover').not(this).is(':visible').css('opacity', 0.2);
```

or

```
$('.poi-hover').not(this).not(':visible').css('opacity', 0.2);
```